# Prove it's an acyclic graph if all the vertices has at most a degree of 1?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

So, I need to prove that only an acyclic graph can have all the vertices where the degree of all the vertices is atmost 1. We are talking about the undirect graph here?

I am confused as I made many  possible acyclic graphs but after one node, every single one of them has a degree of 2.? How can I prove my point.

Comment: The only graphs all of whose vertices have degree at most one are the disconnected unions of isolated vertices and graphs with two vertices and one edge. Are you sure you have correctly stated what you want to prove? Please [edit] the question to quote its source directly.

Comment: Yes, the question is correct @EthanBolker

Comment: I do not get your hint @Peter. With 3 vertices, wouldn't one of them be connected to 2? It is only possible in the case if the 3rd one is isolated. Is that what you are trying to say?

Comment: @Abrehman20 If the question is correct then my comment is an answer. Of course not every acyclic graph is of this kind. You can have an acyclic graph with as many vertices of high degree as you like - think about trees.

Comment: Yes, I got it, Thank you, sir.